# I got a question about php nowdoc

Tags: php

I got a question about php nowdoc

```
<?php
$test = <<< test
<b>my name is $name</b>
test;
echo $test;
?>
```

I would like to output:

my name is $name but i need to do:

```
<?php
$test = <<< test
<b>my name is \$name</b>
test;
echo $test;
?>
```

how can i do it automatic?

I mean about this quote.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a heredoc, not a nowdoc.  To make it a nowdoc, enclose `test` in quotes.  You then don't need to add a backslash.

```
<?php
$test = <<< 'test'
<b>my name is $name</b>
test;
echo $test;
?>
```

From your comment elsewhere, it seems you're using a heredoc rather than a nowdoc because the PHP version you have doesn't support nowdocs.  There's no way to do what you're after with a heredoc - which is why nowdocs were added.  You need to upgrade to a newer version of PHP or think of a different way of meeting your higher-level requirement.

Comment: Not sure why somebody downvoted this.  If it's factually wrong, please let me know - I'll correct or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: i know about nowdoc but it only work in php 5.3~, is there a way to do it in php 5.1?

Comment: There you must escape it.  You can't take a feature of a language and hope it will do something.  You can't will a heredoc to act like a nowdoc :).

Answer (score 0):

Both heredoc and nowdoc are quite useless.

If you come to such a question, you are most likely solving whatever your problem not the best way and there is a better solution for sure.